# bundling Core Data to tableviewcontroller (himself in a navigation controller(himself in a tabbarcontroller))

Tags: ios, ios4, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

I'm new on developping on iPhone and I encounter pretty much problem with my project.

The project, based on empty app : a tabbar app(item1,item2). item1 is a simple viewcontroller(ProfilViewController) and is part of navigationcontroller. a button from item1 push a tableviewcontroller (MainMantraViewController).

Aside, I have my CoreData with a single entity : Mantra,made of 3 attributes:phrase,theme,partage. I try to fill it at the launch to test the bundle between coredata and the tableviewcontroller.

here is my appdelegate.m, under didfinishlaunching:

```
ProfilViewController *rootView =(ProfilViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
rootView.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;

//donnée test
Mantra * newMantra=(Mantra *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Mantra" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
newMantra.phrase =@"ca pu du cul";
newMantra.theme = @"rire";
```

Runnning the app, I get the following ***

- (edited)

***:

```
**2012-05-24 16:26:09.690 Proto v0[1843:fb03] -[UITabBarController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a4a690
2012-05-24 16:26:09.693 Proto v0[1843:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a4a690'**
```

I'm completly stucked at this point and i can't find any conclusive clue anywhere.
I thank you for your help and will provide any helpfull snipets.

Cheers

Comment: The error is saying that something in the program is trying to access the `topViewController` property of an object.  The object is a `UITabBarController` but that property only exists for a `UINavigationController`.  Where do you reference `topViewController`?

Comment: This was a method I found in a  tuto, but it appears it has to be implemented though i thaught it was part of the class.

Comment: The new error is happening because you tell the compiler to treat `rootView` as a `ProfilViewController` but it isn't one; it's a `UITabBarController` instead...according to the error message.  Whenever you use a cast, such as (ProfilViewController *) you need to be 100% sure you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error log is clear enough, you are calling 'topViewController' somewhere on the UITabBarController, but UITabBarController doesn't have a property called 'topViewController'. I think you want to use 'selectedViewController'.

Comment: Ok, I changed to an other method wich used to work with another architecture but the spirit is the same : define a rootview and set the context from it :
        ProfilViewController *rootView =(ProfilViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    rootView.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;

Comment: Oops it wasn't actually the latest error message I receive.

i have updated the one which corresponds to the code in my post.

Comment: But it is the same kind of error, it is telling you that you are trying to cast a method that isn't part of UITabBarController ;) I assume you have the managedObjectContext property in the ProfilViewController.h file? So just use _profileViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext.